# Symfony Ajax Form - Choice Type Options depend on other unmapped Choice Type Options

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

i try to keep it short.

**I want to change the possible choice opotion of my ChoiceType(N.2), depending on another ChoiceType(N.1).**

- My ChoiceType(N.1) is unmapped and has the Option "Yes" or "No"
- My ChoiceType(N.2) is mapped and filled with categorys out of an database.

*The database has the Columns ID(int) | Name(string) |
Revenue(boolean)*

**So if the user chooce the Option Yes, i want all Categorys in the ChoiceType (N.2) with the revenue of 1(true). If the user choose No, i want to display all choice options with the categorys with the revenue of 0 (boolean)**

I've done a lot of research but I just can't get it to work.
I mainly focus on de documentaion https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html, but there both ChoiceTyps are Entitys, not just one. I should almost have it, but I don't know what's missing.
Here are the important parts of my code:

**EntryForm:**

```
   ->add('choice', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'  => [
                'No' => 0,
                'Yes' => 1,
            ],
            'data'=>0,
            'mapped' => false,
        ])

 

 
        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $choice) {
   
           
            $revenue = $choice;
            $user = $this->security->getUser();
            $userId = $user->getId();

            $form->add('category', EntityType::class,[
                'class'=>Category::class,
                'query_builder' => function(CategoryRepository $repository) use($userId,    
                         $revenue) {
                    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u');
           
                    return $qb
           
                        ->where('u.user=' .$userId, 'u.revenue='.   $revenue );
                }, ]);
           
        };
 
 
       
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
 
                $data = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $choice = $form->get('choice')->getData();
 
                $formModifier($event->getForm(),  $choice);
            }
        );
 

 
        $builder->get('choice')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
         
                $choice = $event->getForm()->getData();
     
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $choice);
            }
        );
```

**AJAX**

```
var $choice = $('#entry_choice');
 
    $choice.change(function() {
   
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var data = {};
     
        var choice = $('#entry_choice').val();
         
         data= choice;
           data[$choice] = 1;
           
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
           data : data,
           
            complete: function(html) {
                console.log( data);
                  
              $('#entry_category').replaceWith(
      
        
      $(html.responseText).find('#entry_category'));
     
            }
        });
    });
```

I think I don't understand the data passed from ajax correctly.
I am trying to achieve the following:  If the user change the ChoiceType from No to Yes, pass the variable $choice with the value 1 to the form. In the form at the  $formModifier it should change the variable $revenue to $choice, so that i can filter with my query_builder through all categorys where revenue is 1.  ('u.revenue='.   $revenue)

Kind regards Magnus

Comment: Forms tend to expect the data in the format `form_name[field_name]=value`, so in your case your `data` should contain `{ 'entry_form[choice]': choice_value }`. Try inspecting a request to confirm with a regular submission, it depends on how your controller expects the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `data[$choice] = 1;` try `data[$choice.attr('name')] = 1;`

Symfony expects the data to be sent from the front end in a specific format.

If you inspect the source of the generated html form, you will see that format.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. That was my problem, now the parameter are correct and the ajax request ist successfull. My second problem now is, that there is an entry in my database when i switch from the choices yes to no or no to yes. I really dont understand why, because in my jsfile i just replace the $entry_category field with the thml.responsetext. The whole data of the form should be submitted to the database when the user press the SubmitType button, but not when he just switch the choicetype from yes to no.